# Error in executing Customised WordCount jar in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-emr, emr

Hi I am trying to execute customised WordCount jar on AWs EMR.

My word count jar is working properly because I tried adding it as a step without job arguments and it is running successfully. My problem is when I run it with job arguments.
In my s3 I have 2 folders

```
Jar location -> s3n://word-count123/WordCount.jar
jar Arguments ->s3n://word-count123/input
                s3n://word-count123/output
```

input folder contains one txt file and output folder one txt file. 
Am I doing something wrong? I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks.

P.S I dont wanna execute it from CLI.

Comment: can you check the debug logs in S3 folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just executed a existing WordCount jar.. Seems to be a problem with my JAR.